# How to change image url?

Tags: images, urls, attachments

How can I change the image url from this

> http://i0.wp.com/example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/imagename

Into this:

> http://www.example.com/image/imagename.jpg

Or into this:

> http://www.example.com/imagename.jpg

Any suggestions to to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you're using the *Photon* service from `wordpress.org`. So to get rid of the `http://i0.wp.com/` part, you would need to turn it off in you *JetPack* plugin. Are these cosmetic changes only or needed for something else?

Comment: Needed for something else. It is possible to make it as www.example.com/nameofimage.jpg instead of this http://i0.wp.com/example.com/wp-content/uploads/imagename?

Comment: 'Something else', can you expand on that? As @birgire explained, it is impossible while using a CDN service such as Jetpacks Photon service

Comment: I've disabled already the jetpacks. How it possible to make this kind of url for medias -> www.example.com/mediasname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into your WordPress **Dashboard > Settings > Media** and then untick the option that says

> Organize my folders into Month and Year based folders

This will make it look like:

> http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/imagename.jpg

Then to take it further you need to update you **config.php** file and add in either this line:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'image/'.'files' );
```

This will give you:

> http://www.example.com/image/imagename.jpg

Or this:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'files' );
```

...to get:

> http://www.example.com/imagename.jpg

Comment: In my parent theme files? Or one of this /public_html/wp-config.php

/public_html/wp-admin/setup-config.php

/public_html/core_20140602-050214/wp-config.php

/public_html/core_20140602-050214/wp-admin/setup-config.php

/public_html/wp-content_stock/plugins/akismet/views/config.php

/public_html/wp-content/plugins/akismet/views/config.php

Comment: Your wp-config.php file will normally be in the root directory you installed WordPress. You will see within the directory, the wp-content, wp-admin and wp-includes folders. So in your case This will be the correct one. > /public_html/wp-config.php